# While coding my Function.js for my Discord.js bot i get forEach undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach, discord, discord.js, undefined

When coding my function.js
i get a forEach undefined error as listed below if anyone could please help that would be great

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const bot = client;
module.exports = (bot) => {

    fs.readdir("./handlers/", (err, files) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
        if (jsfiles.length <= 0) return console.log("There are no events to load...");
        console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} events...`);
        jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
            require(`./handlers/${f}`);
            console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`);
        });
    });

    fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

        if (jsfiles.length <= 0) return console.log("There are no commands to load...");

        console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands...`);
        jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
            let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
            console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`);
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
            props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                bot.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
            });
        });
    });

};
```

the console replied

> /home/runner/Bot-addon/functions.js:29
> props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
> at /home/runner/Bot-addon/functions.js:29:32
> at Array.forEach ()
> at /home/runner/Bot-addon/functions.js:25:17
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23)

Comment: the error says that `props.help.aliases` is `undefined` you should check why that is

Comment: why are you setting `bot = client`? You can just set `const bot = new Discord.Client()`. Also, if you don't add aliases to each command you can just check if there are any aliases `if (props.help.aliases)`